Corrosion on Stainless steel instalation
I'm working on a project that involves using a huge carbon steel buffer tank in a stainless steel piping system (close water chiller system). I'm concerned about potential corrosion issues that could arise from this combination.
Has anyone here had experience with a similar setup? If so, what precautions or measures did you take to prevent corrosion and ensure the system's longevity?
Thanks

Is the stainless going to corrode? if that is an issue then don't use dissimilar metals...

Could you use some kind of lining in the tank? Rust from the carbon steel tank can pull chromium from stainless steel, turning it into stained steel.

Normally one adds anti-corrosion additives to the water. Pure water is quite corrosive.

As @SolarMIke points out there is a problem with the use of dissimilar materials. Because of the difference in electropotential between carbon steel and stainless steel there will be galvanic action causing corrosion wherever the two are in contact. This can be greatly reduced by having a dielectric sleeve between the two, as is common in domestic heating systems where you have a steel tank and copper pipes. Also, make sure the water is free of dissolved oxygen.

Hi, thanks everyoner. My problem is not the direct corrosion contact since that we will use separation joint. The problem is if the small particles that end up coming out of the buffer tank will contaminate the rest of the installation and causing future problems like corrosion of the stainless steel?

If the chiller water is conditioned by buffering it to an alkaline pH while deoxygenating it, then the plain steel will not corrode. This prevents direct chemical attack. There are commercially-available conditioning chemicals you can buy to do this periodically.
It is always good practice to also separate out the dissimilar metals with insulated pipe joints that prevent electrical contact between the steel tank shell and the stainless piping. This prevents galvanic corrosion. These fitments are also commonly available.
Certain grades of stainless are susceptible to crevice corrosion in clamped or screwed joints; this corrosion mode is sensitively dependent on the salinity and pH of the chiller water. When specifying the type of stainless to use, you must know in advance what the salinity and pH of the conditioned water will be.

Hi Niels, thank you. Do you think there will be an issue with small particle contamination from the carbon steel buffer tank, leading to contamination in the rest of the installation, which uses stainless steel pipes?

No, so long as the water is conditioned.
